# How to get fields from Elasticsearch with Node.js client

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am trying to get fields from `localhost:9200/monIndex/monType/_mapping`

I am using the Elasticsearch API:

```
client.indices.getMapping({
  index: 'monIndex',
  type:'monType',       
}).then(function (response) {           
  callback(response);                               
});
```

The response returned is the object containing the `_mapping` from ES, but I only need to retrieve fields.

I have a nested mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is :

```
<host>:<port>/<index|indices>/_mapping/field/<field|fields>
```

For eg:

```
localhost:9200/monIndex/_mapping/field/monType
```

documentation : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-field-mapping.html

Comment: Thank you very much , but i don't need all shema to the field , and i was obliged to get the json file from es with the client nodsjs of elasticsearch  and then doing some treatment to get only the fields with lodash and underscore libraries

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`indices.getFieldMapping`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-getfieldmapping) instead of `getMapping`:

```
client.indices.getFieldMapping({
  index: 'monIndex',
  type:'monType',   
  fields: 'field1,field2,field3'    
}).then(function (response) {           
  callback(response);                               
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but for me it was the same result when getting the mapping of only one field or the mapping of all the fields , i must treat the response then as a string array and then using string libraries to get only the fields like that, id | name , not like that ,author.id | author.age.